# How to get errors of the file using OTA?

Tags: delphi, opentools

I'd like to access the errors on the active file (.pas).
Now a days I can find it on the left side of the IDE, as you can see on image.

I found on OTA the interface IOTAModuleErrors, that seems to be what I want. But I didn't found it on BorlandIDEServices.QueryInterface or BorlandIDEServices.GetService. Someone knows how to access it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it! 
It was much simpler than I thought, it's just a matter of casting the IOTAModule on the module to IOTAModuleErrors.

If you want a practical example you can check [this project](https://github.com/rfrezino/RFindUnit) 
I use on the unit Source/FindUnit.OTAUtils.pas, on function GetErrorListFromActiveModule.

Sample:

```
function GetErrorsListFromActiveModule: TOTAErrors;
var
  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  ModuleErrors: IOTAModuleErrors;
begin
  ModuleServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices;
  Assert(Assigned(ModuleServices));
  ModuleErrors := ModuleServices.CurrentModule as IOTAModuleErrors;
  Result := ModuleErrors.GetErrors(ModuleServices.CurrentModule.FileName);
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some sample code for the benefit of future readers here? That would make a much better and more complete answer.

Comment: Ok, tomorrow I post a short code, I dont have Delphi on my personal pc.